# Allow duplicate keys in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a check column (active)

TABLE

```
ID    USER    ACTIVE
1     Mike    0
2     Mark    1
3     Paul    1
4     John    0
```

And results stored on Array

```
$check = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mod_users");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $check[] = $row['active'];       
}
```

I need to check array results in a while cycle:

```
in_array($foo, $check)
```

Exist a way to **allow duplicate keys** for $check array?

Comment: Please take some time to read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189).

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What is in $foo and why are you checking against the "active" column? Your code doesn't really make much sense as you're filling your array with non-unique values.

Comment: Why check array results? You can filter them on your MySQL query by adding `WHERE ACTIVE = 1` (ACTIVE) OR `WHERE ACTIVE = 0`(INACTIVE).

Comment: Duplicate keys? Isn't a key unique by definition?

Comment: @elclanrs Normally keys are an index by default afaik.

Comment: Being that this is a non-associative array, the uniqueness of the keys shouldn't matter because they will simply be identified by their position in the array and will, in effect, be unique by default.

So if you were to add two "active" values (0, 1) and dump your array, you'll get Array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) }

Answer (score 0):

No. It does not make any sence.

You can use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for check.

```
count(array_keys($check, $foo));
```

Or [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
count(array_filter($check, function($value)use($foo){return $value==$foo;}));
```